# How to increment different numbers in a text in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to fill about 2k rows in excel which would hurt my brain to do it manually... But after 4hours of searching and trying to solve this problem I'm really close to give it up.

Here is a simple example: A101.0 which is used as a code for a position. The .0 is going to .0 to .6, then the 01 should increase by 1 to look like A102.0 and so on. The 01 which is before the . is going to 57 so the last would look like A157.6. And after this the number near the A should go up to 2, like this. A201.0 and starting over the cycle again.

The very last should looks like this: A657.6

So A is fix, first number is going 1 to 6, the 2 next to it is going 01 to 57 for every "1 to 6" and the last number after the dot is going 0 to 6 for every "01 to 57" number.

I wrote a little macro but not working so well...

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For k = 1 To 6
    For j = 1 To 57
        For i = 1 To 7

            Munka1.Cells(i * j * k, 10).Value = "A" & k & j & i - 1

        Next i
    Next j
Next k

End Sub
```

If there is any solution whithout vba it would be good also.

Comment: Write 8 first "numbers" in a question in one row comma separated because your algorithm is not clear.

Comment: Your question is not understandable for me. Maybe I am tired... Please, edit your question and place a picture (if not something editable) with some relevant strings you have to process (before picture) and another one with the desired result for the range presented before. Otherwise, your question is difficult to be understood and the code does not help, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your macro is fine, it's just this: `i * j * k` that is bad. Multiplying those numbers together is not going to give you an integer that corresponds to an excel row. Instead you'll need one more variable to track the row to which you write the incremented value:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim writeRow as Integer

writeRow = 1

For k = 1 To 6
    For j = 1 To 57
        For i = 1 To 7

            Munka1.Cells(writeRow, 10).Value = "A" & k & j & "." & i - 1
            writeRow = writeRow + 1

        Next i
    Next j
Next k

End Sub
```

Updated to add: I also stuck a `& "." &` in there to include the decimal in your outputted string location value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel O365 with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can enter, in a single cell, the formula:

```
=TEXT((INT(SEQUENCE(6*57*7,,0)/(57*7))+1)*100+(MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(6*57*7,,1,1/7))-1,57)+1)+MOD( SEQUENCE(6*57*7,,0),7)/10,"A000.0")
```

and it will spill down to create the series you describe.

[image]

Comment: That's a nice oneliner and (like how I tried myself) based on pure math. Good job =)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you want. Stringing numbers together the way you are is going to cause problems when `k` jumps from 9 to 10 as the `k` string is now 2 digits:

[image]

You can build the number numerically instead and then force it into a format of your choosing:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, y As Long
y = 1 ' y is used as the writing pointer
For k = 1 To 6
    For j = 1 To 57
        For i = 0 To 6
            Munka1.Cells(y, 10).Value = "A" & Format((k * 100) + j + (i / 10), "000.0")
            y = y + 1
        Next i
    Next j
Next k

End Sub
```

---

Finally, if you really wanted to  concatenate your numbers instead of using math(s), you could use:

```
Munka1.Cells(y, 10).Value = "A" & k & Right("0" & j, 2) & "." & i
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"If there is any solution whithout vba it would be good also."*

Instead of VBA, you could use the following formula in `A1` and drag down:

```
=IF(ROUNDUP(ROW()/399,0)>6,"","A"&ROUNDUP(ROW()/399,0)&TEXT(MOD(ROUNDUP(ROW()/7,0)-1,57)+1,"00")&"."&MOD(ROW(A1)-1,7))
```

[image]

I stuck the `IF` in there to start showing blanks after `A657.6` or rather, row 2395.